# Transition to UINavigationBar with transparent background image results in black flickering

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I want to navigate from a white `UINavigatinonBar`to a transparent `UINavigationBar`.

In my root view controller, this is the setup:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
```

It's important that it stays non translucent. 
This is the setup in the second view controller:

```
// set title of navbar 
self.title = [self.data objectForKey:@"title"];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];
//

// IMPORTANT PART: make the nav bar transaparent - no prerequisites. 
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;

// set custom back button
UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(16, 31, 22, 20)];
UIImage *backImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backButtonDetail"];
[backButton setBackgroundImage:backImage  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(popBack) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButtonItem;
```

This goes almost well, except for the animation:

[image]

As you can see, the background becomes black when I animate it. I want to fade the white into the destination color. It now animates from the black background.

I tried settings a custom `UIView` underneath the nav bar, but that didn't work.

I'm quite lost about how to about this now and any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try placing a UIImageView and set it's colour to white in your second View Controller. Make sure that it fills behind the Navigation Bar so that the Nav Bar is usable.

Comment: Have you found a fix for your issue? Thanks.

Comment: Nope not yet.. I'll be very happy with someone who can provide me with an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently ran into this same problem and was able to get around it by just setting the window's background color in the appDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
window.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

and if you don't already have a reference to window then

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window.backgroundColor = ...
```

I found this to be the cleanest solution. Hope it helps, albeit a bit late.